# Is there a way to have different edge splines between nodes in the same cluster vs between nodes in different clusters using fdp layout in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am creating a graph with multiple clusters. There are edges between nodes belonging to the same cluster, and edges between nodes belonging to different clusters. I am using `fdp` layout. Is there a way to have one type of edge routing for nodes within a cluster, and another type of edge routing for nodes belonging to different clusters?

For example, I would like to use `splines=ortho` for the former, and `splines=compound` for the latter. I tried doing just that, but it appears that the generated graph just uses the `splines` value specified in the main graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure it can't be done with a single pass - **splines** is a graph-level attribute.  However I think it could be done with a 5-pass technique:

0. edit the input file

- move all intra-cluster edges inside the cluster
- add **edge[keep=1]** to the beginning of each cluster

1. run **fdp -Tdot -Gsplines=ortho**  (applies to all) to add node & edge routing
2. run step 1 output through **gvpr** (or **python**?) to

- pin all nodes **node[pin=true]** at the beginning of the graph
- for every edge where keep==1, copy **pos** attribute to (new) **keeppos** attribute

3. run step 2 output through **fdp -s -Tdot -Gsplines=compound** - this will overwrite all edge pos values
4. run step 3 output through **gvpr** (or **python**?) to replace **pos** with **keeppos** (if **keeppos**!="")
5. run step 4 output through **neato -s -n2 -Tsvg/png/...**

Whew! Sounds gross, but it seems to work
p.s. **-s** option is needed on steps 3 and 5 to fix scaling issues
p.p.s. because pinning nodes is required, **fdp** and **neato** only (not **dot**)

Here is a command line:

```
f=multispline.gv;
F=`basename $f .gv`
fdp -Gsplines=true -Tdot $f | 
gvpr -c 'N{pin="true"}E[keep=="1"]{keeppos=$.pos}'| 
fdp -s -Gsplines=ortho -Tdot | 
gvpr -c 'E[keeppos!=""]{pos=keeppos}' | 
neato -s -n2 -Tsvg >oo.svg
```