# Graphs with mixed splines OR merge layers with different splines

Tags: r, graphviz, diagrammer, patchwork

I want to create a graph with both `splines=line` and `splines=splines`, similar to the image below.

However, to achieve this, I had to create two separate graphs via the `R` package `DiagrammeR` and combine them using the `figpatch` and `patchwork` packages.

Is this possible just with `graphviz`? I'm not 100% certain, but I don't think it is… But just want to cover all bases to make sure.

Can someone please confirm / deny my hunch. If the latter, some examples or resources on how to do so would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more info about my questions.

[image]

### Graphs

Below is the code used to generate the graphs.

*Graph 1:* The one on the left.

```
digraph dot {

    // splines = curved;
    node[fontname = arial, width=1.5, height=1.5, shape=circle, fontsize=50, style = filled, penwidth = 3];
    edge[fontname = arial, penwidth = 3.6, fontsize = 50]

    RItb0  [pos = "000,0", style = invis, fillcolor = palevioletred];
    RIpb0  [pos = "100,0", style = invis, fillcolor = darkseagreen3];
    RIsi0  [pos = "200,0", style = invis, fillcolor = white];
    RIbhs0 [pos = "300,0", style = invis, fillcolor = mediumorchid3];
    RIdep0 [pos = "400,0", style = invis, fillcolor = cadetblue3];
    RItb   [pos = "000,100", width = 3, height = 3, fillcolor = palevioletred];
    RIpb   [pos = "100,100", width = 3, height = 3, fillcolor = darkseagreen3];
    RIsi   [pos = "200,100", width = 3, height = 3, fillcolor = white];
    RIbhs  [pos = "300,100", width = 3, height = 3, fillcolor = mediumorchid3];
    RIdep  [pos = "400,100", width = 3, height = 3, fillcolor = cadetblue3];
    tb1    [pos = "000,200", style = invis, fillcolor = palevioletred];
    pb1    [pos = "100,200", style = invis, fillcolor = darkseagreen3];
    si1    [pos = "200,200", style = invis, fillcolor = white];
    bhs1   [pos = "300,200", style = invis, fillcolor = mediumorchid3];
    dep1   [pos = "400,200", style = invis, fillcolor = cadetblue3];

    {   edge [weight = 10, minlen = 4.0; style = invis, penwidth = 3];
        // Random Intercepts
        RItb0  -> RIpb0  ; // [minlen = 4.0];
        RIpb0  -> RIsi0  ; // [minlen = 4.0];
        RIsi0  -> RIbhs0 ; // [minlen = 4.0];
        RIbhs0 -> RIdep0 ; // [minlen = 4.0];
        RItb   -> RIpb   ; // [minlen = 4.0];
        RIpb   -> RIsi   ; // [minlen = 4.0];
        RIsi   -> RIbhs  ; // [minlen = 4.0];
        RIbhs  -> RIdep  ; // [minlen = 4.0];
        tb1    -> pb1  ;
        pb1    -> si1  ;
        si1    -> bhs1 ;
        bhs1   -> dep1 ;
    }

    // autogregrssive paths
    {   rank = same; RItb0  -> RItb  [style = invis, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, color = palevioletred, style = invis]; }
    {   rank = same; RItb   -> tb1   [style = invis, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, color = palevioletred, style = invis]; }
    {   rank = same; RIpb0  -> RIpb  [style = invis, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".28"]; }
    {   rank = same; RIpb   -> pb1   [style = invis, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".28"]; }
    {   rank = same; RIsi0  -> RIsi  [style = invis, labelangle = 29.0, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, headlabel = ".35"]; }
    {   rank = same; RIsi   -> si1   [style = invis, labelangle = 29.0, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, headlabel = ".35"]; }
    {   rank = same; RIbhs0 -> RIbhs [style = invis, labelangle = 29.0, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".43"];}
    {   rank = same; RIbhs  -> bhs1  [style = invis, labelangle = 29.0, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".43"];}
    {   rank = same; RIdep0 -> RIdep [style = invis, labelangle = 29.0, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, color = cadetblue3; style = invis]; }
    {   rank = same; RIdep  -> dep1  [style = invis, labelangle = 29.0, labeldistance = 4.3, minlen = 6, color = cadetblue3; style = invis]; }

    {
    // cross-lagged paths
        edge[style = dashed, labeldistance = 4.3, labelfloat = false, constraint = true, minlen = 5]
        RIpb  -> RItb  [penwidth = 5, dir = both, label = ".47"];
        RIpb  -> RIbhs [penwidth = 5, dir = both, label = ".55"];
        RIpb  -> RIdep [penwidth = 5, dir = both, label = ".67"];
        RItb  -> RIbhs [penwidth = 5, dir = both, label = ".60"];
        RItb  -> RIdep [penwidth = 5, dir = both, label = ".58"];
        RItb  -> RIsi  [penwidth = 9.5, dir = both, style = dashed, label = ".27"];
        RIbhs -> RIsi  [penwidth = 9.5, dir = both, style = dashed, label = ".31"];
        RIdep -> RIsi  [penwidth = 9.5, dir = both, style = dashed, label = ".37"];
        RIbhs -> RIdep [penwidth = 5, dir = both, label = ".62"];
    }
}
```

*Graph 2:* The one on the right.

```
digraph dot {
    splines = line;
    node[fontname = arial, width=1.5, height=1.5, shape=circle, fontsize=36, style = filled, penwidth = 3];
    edge[fontname = arial, penwidth = 3.6, fontsize = 28]

    tb1  [pos = "000,200", fillcolor = palevioletred];
    pb1  [pos = "100,200", fillcolor = darkseagreen3];
    si1  [pos = "200,200", fillcolor = white];
    bhs1 [pos = "300,200", fillcolor = mediumorchid3];
    dep1 [pos = "400,200", fillcolor = cadetblue3];
    tb2  [pos = "000,300", fillcolor = palevioletred];
    pb2  [pos = "100,300", fillcolor = darkseagreen3];
    si2  [pos = "200,300", fillcolor = white];
    bhs2 [pos = "300,300", fillcolor = mediumorchid3];
    dep2 [pos = "400,300", fillcolor = cadetblue3];
    tb3  [pos = "000,400", fillcolor = palevioletred];
    pb3  [pos = "100,400", fillcolor = darkseagreen3];
    si3  [pos = "200,400", fillcolor = white];
    bhs3 [pos = "300,400", fillcolor = mediumorchid3];
    dep3 [pos = "400,400", fillcolor = cadetblue3];
    tb4  [pos = "000,500", fillcolor = palevioletred];
    pb4  [pos = "100,500", fillcolor = darkseagreen3];
    si4  [pos = "200,500", fillcolor = white];
    bhs4 [pos = "300,500", fillcolor = mediumorchid3];
    dep4 [pos = "400,500", fillcolor = cadetblue3];
    tb5  [pos = "000,600", fillcolor = palevioletred];
    pb5  [pos = "100,600", fillcolor = darkseagreen3];
    si5  [pos = "200,600", fillcolor = white];
    bhs5 [pos = "300,600", fillcolor = mediumorchid3];
    dep5 [pos = "400,600", fillcolor = cadetblue3];

    {   edge [weight = 10, minlen = 4.0; style = invis, penwidth = 3];
        tb1   -> pb1  ;
        pb1   -> si1  ;
        si1   -> bhs1 ;
        bhs1  -> dep1 ;
        tb2   -> pb2  ;
        pb2   -> si2  ;
        si2   -> bhs2 ;
        bhs2  -> dep2 ;
        tb3   -> pb3  ;
        pb3   -> si3  ;
        si3   -> bhs3 ;
        bhs3  -> dep3 ;
        tb4   -> pb4  ;
        pb4   -> si4  ;
        si4   -> bhs4 ;
        bhs4  -> dep4 ;
        tb5   -> pb5  ;
        pb5   -> si5  ;
        si5   -> bhs5 ;
        bhs5  -> dep5 ;
    }

    // autogregrssive paths
    {   rank = same; tb1   -> tb2  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = palevioletred, style = invis]; }
    {   rank = same; tb2   -> tb3  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = palevioletred, headlabel = ".37"]; }
    {   rank = same; tb3   -> tb4  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = palevioletred, headlabel = ".28"]; }
    {   rank = same; tb4   -> tb5  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = palevioletred, headlabel = ".30"]; }
    {   rank = same; pb1   -> pb2  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".28"]; }
    {   rank = same; pb2   -> pb3  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = darkseagreen3; style = invis]; }
    {   rank = same; pb3   -> pb4  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".30"]; }
    {   rank = same; pb4   -> pb5  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".45"]; }
    {   rank = same; si1   -> si2  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, style = bold, headlabel = ".35"]; }
    {   rank = same; si2   -> si3  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, style = bold, headlabel = ".25"]; }
    {   rank = same; si3   -> si4  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, style = bold; style = invis]; }
    {   rank = same; si4   -> si5  [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, style = bold, headlabel = ".27"]; }
    {   rank = same; bhs1  -> bhs2 [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".43"];}
    {   rank = same; bhs2  -> bhs3 [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".49"]; }
    {   rank = same; bhs3  -> bhs4 [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".50"]; }
    {   rank = same; bhs4  -> bhs5 [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".48"]; }
    {   rank = same; dep1  -> dep2 [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = cadetblue3; style = invis]; }
    {   rank = same; dep2  -> dep3 [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = cadetblue3, headlabel = ".25"]; }
    {   rank = same; dep3  -> dep4 [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = cadetblue3, headlabel = ".27"]; }
    {   rank = same; dep4  -> dep5 [labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, minlen = 16, color = cadetblue3, headlabel = ".37"]; }

    {
    // cross-lagged paths
        edge[style = dashed, labelangle = -39.5, labeldistance = 3.6, labelfloat = true]
        ## [headlabel=<<table border="0" cellborder="0"><tr><td bgcolor="white">Head Label</td></tr></table>>,taillabel="Tail Label"]
        bhs1 -> pb2 [labelangle = 39.5, color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".39"];
        bhs2 -> pb3 [labelangle = 39.5, color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".25"];
        bhs3 -> pb4 [labelangle = 39.5, color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".31"];
        bhs3 -> si4 [color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".30"];
        bhs4 -> tb5 [color = mediumorchid3, headlabel = ".25"];
        dep4 -> pb5 [labelangle = 39.5, color = cadetblue3,    headlabel = ".26"];
        pb2 -> tb3  [color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".25"];
        pb3 -> si4  [color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".30"];
        pb3 -> dep4 [color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".35"];
        pb3 -> bhs4 [color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".28"];
        pb4 -> dep5 [color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".30"];
        pb4 -> bhs5 [color = darkseagreen3, headlabel = ".27"];
        si1 -> bhs2 [headlabel = ".19"];
        si1 -> dep2 [headlabel = ".17"];
        si1 -> pb2  [headlabel = ".14"];
        si2 -> pb3  [headlabel = ".16"];
        tb2 -> si3  [color = palevioletred, headlabel = ".15"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the **splines** attribute applies to the entire graph, so it can't be done with a single invocation / pass of a Graphviz tool

Yes - Chop your graph into multiple graphs, each cluster into its own graph. Each (new) graph can have a different **splines** value.  Run each (new) graph through `dot -Tdot` to determine layouts of each separately. Run those results through **gvpack** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf 2) to combine them into a single graph. And finally hand that to `neato -n2` (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords) to produce an output file.
Like so:

```
S="";
for f in sub[12].gv;  # sub1.gv and sub2.gv are the two created graphs
do 
  T=dot; 
  F=`basename $f .gv`;
  dot -T$T $f >$F.$T; 
  S="$S  $F.$T"; 
done; 
gvpack -array_i3  $S |
  neato -n2 -Tpng >O.png
```

Note - if necessary, it is possible to apply different **splines** values to individual edges by running a dot-formatted graph through `neato -n2` multiple times, each time changing the **splines** value and removing individual edge **pos** values.  Possible, but messy.

Comment: Here is another take on the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687030/is-there-a-way-to-have-different-edge-splines-between-nodes-in-the-same-cluster

Comment: Thanks @sroush. I'm not a programmer, so apologies for any ignorance, but how would I run your above script? Is it `bash` or some other language?

Comment: Okay, so I got a script up and running in `sh`, however I am getting the error: `Error: node RItb0 in graph dot has no position;
Error loading layout info from graph dot`. I see in the post above that this could be something to do with `pin` or `keep`... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post your graphs

Comment: I've just posted the code. I added the `pos` argument to each node at the top of the graph, so this error is gone now. However, I think I may have an issue with the script calling the relative dir i.e., `Can't open   graph_0.dot  graph_2.dot`. I have different files names.

Comment: Okay, so running manually: `gvpack -array_i3 ./graph_0.gv && gvpack -array_i3 ./graph_2.gv | neato -s -n2 -Tpng >0.png` I get an error re: nodes have last their edge. What do I do with this?

Comment: Try this: **gvpack -array_i3 ./graph_0.gv  ./graph_2.gv | neato -s -n2 -Tpng >0.png**

Comment: By the way, manually adding the **pos** values was not strictly needed (it did not hurt)  **dot -Tdot** should have added **pos** for you

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a number of errors  e.g., `❯ gvpack -array_i3 ./graph_0.gv ./graph_2.gv | neato -s -n2 -Tpng >0.png
Warning: node tb1 in graph[1] dot already defined
Some nodes will be renamed.
Error: lost RItb0 RIpb0 edge
`.  The last error seems to be occurring for every edge and node that has been defined. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237589/discussion-between-atanas-janackovski-and-sroush).

Comment: Okay, so I finally got it working, but not with the script. I still get the Can't open error… Any ideas why this is happening?