# Graphviz dot - possible to mix edge types on the same digraph?

Tags: graphviz, dot

As far as I can see in this example: [How to prevent Graphviz from moving nodes to accomodate an edge - Help - Graphviz](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/how-to-prevent-graphviz-from-moving-nodes-to-accomodate-an-edge/1435) - `splines=polyline;` is an attribute of a graph as a whole: it says in [splines | Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/splines/) that it is "Valid on: Graphs".

And, as far as I can see, there is nothing similar to `splines` in [Edge Attributes | Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/docs/edges/).

So, quite probably, it is *not* possible to mix two types of edges (polyline and spline) in the same digraph -- but I'd still like to make finally sure: for instance, due to being "Valid on: Graphs" - would `splines`  maybe be also valid on subgraphs? If so, then maybe one could use subgraphs, to group edges that should be styled as, say, polyline (or spline - btw, I tried this, did not work for me).

In any case, is there any way, to choose a subset of edges on a Graphviz dot diagram, and have it rendered with a different `splines` setting (say, `polyline`), from the setting of the parent/container digraph (say, `spline`)? (if not, an explicit answer would be much appreciated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the **splines** attribute is a (Root) graph-level attribute.  (all or nothing).  There are no edge-level overrides.  (though that would be nice).

However, there are several ways to combine multiple spline type, but not in one invocation of **dot** (or any of the layout engines) (see below)

The first question should be "Is this really necessary?"

- Sometimes it is.  Here is an example of combining spline types that the user really wanted: [Graphs with mixed splines OR merge layers with different splines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69341993/graphs-with-mixed-splines-or-merge-layers-with-different-splines/69353248#69353248).  Note that the answer describes two ways of accomplishing your goal.
- Sometimes not fully necessary, but just a user (like me) throwing hands in the air and giving up. (Been there, done that).  Polyline frequently gives "mixed" results - but same is true of all the other spline options.
  Anyway, if this is a one-time need, the answers above should suffice, but if is to be used may times and/or automated, that can be accomplished also.  Graphviz has some poorly documented capabilities to "mark" objects (edges in this case) so they can be pre or post processed and then revisited (edge **pos** values erased and then reworked by a n-th engine invocation)